# Adding a numeric value to all rows of a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been attempting to add a numeric "1" or "0" to all rows of a column in a SQL Server database.

Using

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD DEFAULT (1) FOR myfield
```

but I keep getting errors

> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I go and delete the constraint and then run the above with no errors but the field does not update

Is there another way of adding a numeric value to all rows without making it a default value?

Comment: Not completely clear what you want to achieve, but it almost sounds like you should just use an UPDATE query instead of adding a constraint to the table. (UPDATE t SET <col>=1 FROM dbo.<table>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to set all values, an `UPDATE` statement will suffice, if this is what you want to achieve. Something like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 1
```